# Truncate leading zero instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery script to mask an input field. It's a phone number.
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

I want to mask the input field like this:
+32 123 45 67 89

But in Belgium people are used to fill in their phone number like: 0123 45 67 89.
The goal is to truncate the leading zero instantly...

```
  $('.phone').mask('+32000 00 00 00', {placeholder: "Phone number"});
});
```

Comment: `0032 123 45 67 89` would also be a valid telephone number, but not `32 123 45 67 89`

Comment: This is not my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`translation`](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation) option

```js
$('.phone').mask('+32Z00 00 00 00', {
  placeholder: "Phone number",
  translation: {
    'Z': { pattern: /[1-9]/ }
  },
  onInvalid: function(val, e, f, invalid, options) {
    if(val === '+32') {
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha256-Kg2zTcFO9LXOc7IwcBx1YeUBJmekycsnTsq2RuFHSZU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input class="phone" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the input field has the following value: "+32" instead of my placeholder :( Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :( If I load the page there is still "+32" as the placeholder of the input field...

Comment: @FreddyRibs Is the demo provided here working fine? If yes check the version

Comment: Everything works well. There was an error in my code. Thanks a lot, mate!

Answer (score 0):

My very first approach would be this. Quit whitespaces and then quit leading zero if exists.

```js
function truncateLeadingZero(phoneNumber) {
    var noWhiteSpaces = phoneNumber.split(' ').join('');
    while (noWhiteSpaces.length > 9 && noWhiteSpaces[0] === '0') {
        noWhiteSpaces = noWhiteSpaces.substring(1,noWhiteSpaces.length);
    }

    return noWhiteSpaces;
}


var phoneNumber = '0123 45 67 89';
phoneNumber = truncateLeadingZero(phoneNumber)
console.log(phoneNumber);
```

I think that using what you posted in your question, the phone number would be masked as you want if you use my output. What it expects is a string with 9 numbers (each zero of the mask).

`$('.phone').mask('+32000 00 00 00', {placeholder: "Phone number"});`

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
How to combine this with the jquery?